# How can I print the standard deviation of a measurements for each ID using awk?

Tags: awk

I need to print the standard deviation of measurements ($2) for each unique ID ($1).

the data looks like this:

```
101 560  
101 460
101 530  
101 480  
104 600
104 510
104 500
107 450
107 490
107 550
107 500
```

Comment: Awk is not quite the right language. You may want to use R instead. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-min-max-median-and-average-of-a-list-of-numbers-in/13775#13775

Comment: ... or `datamash -Ws groupby 1 sstdev 2 < file` (change to `pstdev` if you want the population standard deviation)

Comment: In any case, this is essentially a subquestion of [Determining averages, stdev, stderror, and counts of values in a list](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325078/determining-averages-stdev-stderror-and-counts-of-values-in-a-list)

Comment: I should be possible, but the people here may not know the formula, add this to the question. Also explain the unique id bit: is it the sub of values for each id. Add examples. Then show us what you have tried. Tell us if you have to use awk, or can use other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R or datamash are probably a better choice!

Following standard deviation definition, we can:

```
$ cat my-sd
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

    { s[$1]["sum"] += $2 ; 
      n = s[$1]["oco"] ++; 
      v[$1][n]=$2  }

END { for(x in s){ 
         m=s[x]["sum"]/s[x]["oco"]; 
         s1=0;
         for(y in v[x]){
            s1 += (v[x][y]-m)*(v[x][y]-m);}
         print x, sqrt(s1/s[x]["oco"])}
    }

$ my-sd example
101 39.6074
104 44.9691
107 35.6195
```