# mean and standard deviation from multiple files

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I have 3000 files (1.out, 2.out, 3.out...., each with a single column something like this:

```
0.446477
0.439331
0.444394
0.425003
0.428981
0.419547
0.432834
0.417874
........
```

I need to calculate average and standard deviation for each row across 3000 files. I could calculate the average using:

```
awk '{a[FNR]+=$1;b[FNR]++;}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)print a[i]/b[i];}' *.out
```

But I am stuck with the calculation of standard deviation.

Comment: Where are you stuck? You don't know the formula for standard deviation?

Comment: @muru The formula is sqrt (1/n*(sum(Xi-mean)^2)). I don't know how to use this in scripting. Thanks !

Comment: You can use `sqrt` in awk: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336613/70524

Comment: do you want to print *average and standard deviation* for each file separately?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : I need a single average i.e. First row from each file to be averaged and written as single line in out file. Followed by second line from each file..like wise. And each row will have a standard deviation value for it's average. Thanks !

Comment: @ashu, still unclear, your "avarage" logic is unclear, should it join all files and take mean of all columns of each row?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : For example:

Input files

1.out

2
4
5
6


2.out

1
2
3
5

3.out

4
5
6
7


Output file should have:

(2+1+4)/3 std_dev1
(4+2+5)/3 std_dev2
(5+3+6)/3 std_dev3
(6+5+7)/3 std_dev4

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : Yes, I need mean of all columns for each row by joining all the individual files. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Complex solution using ***paste*** command and [***datamash***](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) tool:

1. Merging all files into one file for further processing:

   ```
   paste [0-9]*.out | datamash transpose > data
   ```

   -- `datamash transpose`- will transpose rows into columns
2. Getting total number of fields:

   ```
   nf=`awk '{print NF; exit}' data`
   ```
3. Calculating mean and standard deviation:

   ```
   for ((i=1; i<$nf; i++)); do datamash mean $i pstdev $i < data; done
   ```

The output would look like (1st column - mean value, 2nd column - st. deviation value):

```
0.596477    0.11180339887499
0.589331    0.11180339887499
0.594394    0.11180339887499
0.575003    0.11180339887499
0.578981    0.11180339887499
0.569547    0.11180339887499
0.582834    0.11180339887499
.......
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Though looks like datamash is not installed on the Redhat work station I am working. I need to talk to my sys admin for this.

Comment: @ashu, welcome, datamash is indeed a good tool for such cases

Answer (score 1):

[Standard deviation can be calculated in one pass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance) without modifying your script much.

```
awk '{a[FNR]+=$1; b[FNR]++; c[FNR]+=$1*$1 } 
     END{
        for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)
          print a[i]/b[i], sqrt((c[i]-a[i]*a[i]/b[i])/(b[i]-1)) ;
     }
' *.out
```

This is the *naive* implementation, another implementation, the "online method" on the same wiki page :

```
awk '{
  x=$1
  n[FNR] += 1
  delta = x - mean[FNR]
  mean[FNR] += delta/n[FNR]
  delta2 = x - mean[FNR]
  M2[FNR] += delta * delta2
}
END{
for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++)
        if(n[i]<2)
                print mean[i], 0
        else
                print mean[i], sqrt(M2[i]/(n[i]-1))
}' *.out
```